# R Shiny - how to use part of the ui.R SelectInput text into server.R

Tags: r, shiny

This should be a pretty easy question.

I would like to have a SelectInput choices in the *ui.R* side that is composed by two variables, for instance, a number and a text, as the data.frame showed below.

```
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("111","222","333","444","555"),c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE")))
names(df1)<-c("Number","Text")
```

[df1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li50c.png)

So the possible choices should be `111AAA`, `222BBB`, `333CCC`, `444DDD`, `555EEE`.

On the *server* side, let's say that I have `df_111`, `df_222`, `df_333`, `df_444` and `df_555` and I want to plot those data according to the chosen value in the SelectInput *ui.R* side

Once it was chosen `222BBB` for instance, I would like to plot the `df_222` on the *server.R* side.

I was trying to concatenate the `df1` columns to create the SelectInput choices like that:

```
selectInput("ID","Select a number+text",choices = parse(df1$Number,df1$Text, sep=""))
```

It worked fine. But I couldn't use the first part of the selected input (the numeric part `222`, for e.g.) to plot the `df_222` on the *server.R* side.

On the *server.R* side I tried to call the data using:

```
data=eval(parse(text=paste0("df_",input$(ID$number))))
```

The `input$(ID$number)` part sounds to me pretty wrong, despite being intuitive for me, as I am interested in only the first part (numbers) of the selected input. Maybe I should use `reactive` function, I don't know...

If you need any more details, please feel free to ask. I hope it is clear.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will have to use reactives.  To get the data frame you'd want to use `get()` along with some regex to get the numeric part from input$ID e.g. `data <- reactive({get(paste0("df_", readr::parse_number(input$ID)))})`

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I tried it, but it didnt work, it gave me the msg:
<text>:1:13: unexpected symbol
1: bind_213001 CABIN
where `bind_213001` is equivalent to df_111, or df_333 (it is the dataframe that I want to access)

In the console window, I tried to use your code, replacing the input$ID by " 213001 CABIN" (added quotation marks), and it worked (it returned the bind_213001 data frame). 
Why it does not work on ui.R/server.R app? Did I miss something?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Well, I rewrote the code from scratch and it somehow worked... haha thank you guys for your help!!